# Microsoft Azure Blob Storage Upload Performance

Tags: azure-storage

I am running an Azure web role, which is storing very small blobs into Azure storage. (Blob upload is being done from the server, not from the browser.) I have searched stack overflow and the rest of the internet for tips on optimizing blob storage performance, and I believe I've checked and implemented all of the usual suspects: uploading async, allowing unlimited outgoing web connections (which now seems to be the default setting on web roles and no longer needs to be explicitly set in web.config or in code).

Tweaking the number of concurrent uploads I allow makes some difference, but regardless of what I've tried, I seem to **max out at around 1,000 blob uploads per second**. This is when running in the Azure web role, in the same region as the storage account (East US). My rate when running this from home over a good internet connection isn't much less, ~700 blobs/sec, which seems to tell me that it's not the network latency that's limiting the rate, it's the actual processing time of the storage service.

I wouldn't normally consider these rates horrible for this kind of a service, but I've read that Microsoft **boasts a rate of ~20,000 storage transactions per second**, so I've been a little disappointed with these results.

I'd like to get some feedback from those who have really tried to push the limits of blob storage. Does ~1000 small uploads per second sound about right? Or is there possibly something else I should be doing to improve this? I'll post the code if I need to, but I'd rather not receive speculative answers, I'd like to hear from developers who can either confirm that my results are reasonable, or that they've seen much higher throughput.

I should add that I'm currently running this in a small web role. I've tried it also in a medium web role, and didn't see any significant difference.

**EDIT:**
After a few days of development and testing, my upload rate seemed to suddenly increase. Not by a lot, but maybe by another ~200 per second. In looking around the web, I noticed a comment in the Azure documentation stating *"A storage account scales automatically as usage increases."* So I'm wondering if it really is capable of much higher rates, but will not automatically scale up until it sees sustained period of high volume. Some confirmation of that would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Async alone may not allow for maximum throughput. You may also need multi-threading (probably using a thread pool and the appropriate concurrent collection type to feed the threads if needed).

Comment: @techsaint - The async task scheduling should use the thread pool as needed, so I don't believe this is an issue. Also, as I mentioned, all indications have shown that the limitation does not appear to be in how quickly I can get the network requests sent or received, but the time it's taking on the other end.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how small your requests are the problem might be caused by [Nagle’s Algorithm is Not Friendly towards Small Requests](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/06/25/nagle-s-algorithm-is-not-friendly-towards-small-requests.aspx) - although usually I see that with queues / table operations. Try disabling Nagle's and let me know if that makes any difference. As an fyi, you have to disable it prior to establishing the connection otherwise the changes will not take effect.

Jason